# Julia - why does including variables in a module take up so much memory?

Tags: performance, julia

Consider these two functions:

Function 1:

```
function testVec(t,v,k,n)
    for i=1:n
        t .= v .* 3 .+ k .* 4;
    end
end
```

Function 2:

```
module params
r = 3;
end

function testVec2(t,v,k,n)
    for i=1:n
        t .= v .* params.r .+ k .* 4;
    end
end
```

They have drastically different performance:

```
@time testVec([1 2 3 4], [2 3 4 5], [3 4 5 6], 1000)
0.000036 seconds (7 allocations: 496 bytes)

@time testVec2([1 2 3 4], [2 3 4 5], [3 4 5 6], 1000)
0.003180 seconds (4.01 k allocations: 141.109 KiB)
```

Why does including the parameter `r` in a module make the function perform worse?

If I `export` the module `params` and include `r` in `testVec2` without using the prefix `params`, its performance immediately improves (same as `testVec`). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r` in `params` module is a non-`const` global, which makes its type unstable (because some function can assign `r` to something else, of a different type).

Replace `r = 3` with `const r = 3` and the timings will be the same. Also see first section of [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to check whether a variable is type unstable? For example, a function such as `isUnstable()`?

Comment: Doing `@code_warntype testVec2([1 2 3 4], [2 3 4 5], [3 4 5 6], 1000)` gives a lot of information about the types Julia compiler assigns to variables and intermediate values in the computation. Noting any **red** Any type annotations is a clue that something is amiss.

Comment: @tryingtosolve there is also a `@inferred` macro in `Base.Test`.